# $f$ is real valued iff $\overline{ \hat{f}(n) } = \hat{f}(-n)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The problem I am considering is:

For $f$ a $2\pi$-periodic and Riemann integrable function, show that $f$ is real valued iff $\overline{ \hat{f}(n) } = \hat{f}(-n)$.

Here $\hat{f}(n)$ represents the $n$th fourier coefficient.

It is easy to see that $f$ real implies the equality.

Going the other direction, all I am able to deduce is that $\widehat{\bar{f} - f}(n) = 0$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$, which suggests that $f$ is real whenever it is continuous. (Since the Fejer kernel is a good kernel, the Fourier series is Cesaro summable to every point of continuity of $f$.)

I know that I can approximate in $L_1$ norm an integrable function on the disc. However, all this would give (provided that I could translate the equality in terms of the approximating sequence) is that $f$ is real a.e. This also seems to be a dead end.

Can someone suggest an alternative approach?

(I am reading Stein and Shakarachi - Fourier Analysis.)

In the next chapter they discuss the convergence of the partial sums in $L^2$, but I do not think I am allowed to use that. (Again, that would only provide real valued a.e.)

Comment: Please, don't TeX up hyphens!

Comment: Why on earth not?

Comment: A hyphen is not a minus sign.

Comment: Okay, that's fair. :)

Comment: @AreaMan   an answer is given here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168631/real-and-complex-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this isn't true as stated. Let $f$ be $0$ everywhere, except $f(2\pi k)=i$. Then $f$ is Riemann integrable, but the Riemann integral won't pick up the  non-real value at the single point, so $\hat f(n)=0$ for all $n$. Real-valued almost everywhere is the best you can hope for.

Comment: Could you please tell me your opinion in this solution?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168631/real-and-complex-values    thanks.

Comment: mrf is assuming the function is defined on $\mathbb C$ but the claim in Stein's book is for a $f$ defined on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

In part a) of the same question (Fourier Analysis, Stein and Shakiarchi) it is asked to show 
\begin{equation*}
f(\theta) = \hat{f(0)} + \Sigma[\hat{f(n)}+\hat{f(-n)}]cosn\theta + i[\hat{f(n)}-\hat{f(-n)}]sinn\theta
\end{equation*}
Now let $\hat{f(n)}\ =\ a+ib$ and $\hat{f(-n)}\ =\ c+id$, so according to the given condition $a-c=i(b+d)$.

Therefore $\hat{f(n)}+\hat{f(-n)}\ =\ (a+c)+i(b+d)\ =\ 2a$ and $\hat{f(n)}-\hat{f(-n)}\ =\ (a-c)+i(b-d)=2ib$. Now put these values in the equation found in part a) and that will yield that $f$ is a real valued function.

Comment: This seems to contradict the counterexample given by the user mrf.

Comment: yes...mrf is correct...the most we can expect is to be real almost everywhere.

Comment: You've assumed the extra assumption that the fourier series is convergent to $f$, is it ?

Comment: why this seems to contradict  the counterexample given by the @mrf  I think this answer seems tooo reasonable.

Comment: thank u @wanderer :)) this question took me a very long time and Keen-ameteur helped me in it in the following link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168631/real-and-complex-values

Comment: @Keen-ameteur  please look at this solution. thanks.

Comment: @wanderer  this answer assumes that the fourier series is uniformly convergent to f which is not necessarily true ..... could u clarify this point please?