# Real and Complex values.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

$f$ is a $2\pi$-periodic function defined on $\mathbb{R}$.I reached this step,$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\overline{f}(\theta)e^{in\theta} d\theta = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\theta)e^{in\theta} d\theta,$$ Does this means that f is real valued ? If so what is the justification ?

Comment: The fact that $f$ is real valued must be a premise in the problem because if for example  $f(\theta) = e^{ in\theta}$ then the left hand one is $2\pi$ and the right hand one is 0.

It's not a general identity.

Comment: No, it only means that the integral of the imaginary part of $f$ times the imaginary exponential is zero.

Comment: Oh, okay, was the problem to determine what class of functions satisfy this criterion? I misunderstood the context then.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I want to prove letter (e) in this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164411/basic-properties-of-fourier-series-2, and I reached the step that I mentioned above in the question, Could you help me?

Comment: @Squid ...I want to prove letter (e) in this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164411/basic-properties-of-fourier-series-2, and I reached the step that I mentioned above in the question, Could you help me?

Comment: $f$ is a $2\pi$-periodic function defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You should encode your exact question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the answer but I may be wrong.

You can write $f(t)$=$f_1(t)$+i$f_2(t)$.

From the equality you've written you get that $2i\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f_2(\theta)e^{in\theta} d\theta=0$.

{$e^{in\theta}$} is a hilbert base for the space of $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$, thus if $<e^{in\theta},f>=0$  for every $n \in \Bbb Z$ then $f=0$.

Therefore $f_2(\theta)=0$.

Comment: Is it an answer if $f$ is a $2\pi$- periodic function defined on $ \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Good, with a little dressing . $B=\{e^{in\theta}: n\in \mathbb Z\}$ is an orthogonal Hilbert-space basis for $L^2[-\pi,\pi] .$ And the inner product of $(f -\bar f)$ with $e^{in\theta}$ is the integral. So if $(f -\bar f)$ is orthogonal to every member of $B$ then $f-\bar f=0$.

Comment: Yes. Essentially a $2 \pi$ periodic function can be written as a fourier series with the fourier cooeficents $<e^{in\theta},f>$. The Imaginary part of $f$ is a $2\pi$ periodic functions whose fourier cooeficents are all $0$.
Therefore the Imaginary part is 0.

Comment: @user254665 . but the function is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ not C, So I think that your answer is not suitable for my question..

Comment: It's from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur.....what do u mean by saying that $e^{in\theta}$ is a hilbert base for the space of $L^{2}[−\pi,\pi].$Do you have a proof for this?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur...... what is in the definition of the function that say that the codomain is $\mathbb{C}$?.... could u explain?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur.....why did u considered that we are in the space $L^{2}[-\pi, \pi]?$

Comment: The integral (aside from a having a notation for complex comjugate) is a product of the function and another function whose codomain is $\mathbb{C}$,  which means the function's co-domain could be $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Also the definition (he gave) of the fourier cooeficent is the same as the
inner product: $<e^{inx},f(x)>$, if $e^{inx},f(x) \in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$.
Also to the best of my knowledge, the natural discussion for the fourier cooeficents is when discussing Hilbert spaces and a Hilbert base for such spaces.